# Will dispatch_async inside autoreleasepool cause issues?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, semaphore, midi, autorelease

I'm parsing midi messages inside an autoreleasepool. After determining the message that's being sent, I make calls to the main thread using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(). This seems to work well most of the time but occasionally I'll get a crash where it stops on the line

```
while (semaphore_wait(midiReceivedSemaphore) == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
```

The method looks something like this:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    unsigned int maxPacketLength = 0x100;
    unsigned char* data = malloc(maxPacketLength);
    UInt16 length;

    while (semaphore_wait(midiReceivedSemaphore) == KERN_SUCCESS ) {

        midi_packet_buffer_next_packet_length(midiPacketBuffer, &length);
        if( length > 0) {

            length = midi_packet_buffer_read(midiPacketBuffer, data, length);

            for (unsigned int packetContentsIndex = 0; packetContentsIndex < length; packetContentsIndex++) {
                while (packetContentsIndex < length) {
                    Byte command = data[packetContentsIndex];

                    switch (command) {
                        case 0xA0: //aftertouch
                            commandLength += 2;
                            int meterChannel = data[packetContentsIndex +1];
                            int meterValue = data[packetContentsIndex +2];

                            if (meterValue < 0x10)
                            {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [delegate sendLevelMeterPT:meterChannel withValue:meterValue ];

                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(data);
}
```

Is this a very bad way of handling the MIDI messages? The reason I used dispatch_async is so that it wouldn't slow down the midi processing thread, before using dispatch_async the method was missing some messages if they were coming in fast. Now it catches all the messages but I get the occasional crash. I'm thinking I might have to rewrite the whole midi processing method but want to know the proper way to go about it. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Sorry, Originally I posted an answer that after rereading your code is not going to be helpful.  This seems unrelated but checking the 'length' result of midi_packet_buffer_next_packet_length might be helpful to prevent overruns ( also being careful about the data[packetContentsIndex +2] line).     Can you give more info about the crash?

Comment: Also I'm assuming the code you're showing is NOT running on the main queue, because it looks like you are maintaining your own loop.

Comment: Yeah it's running on a separate thread. The crash will sometimes happen when closing the DAW software that is being controlled, or switching to a new project within the same software. So I'm thinking the midi processing thread is not getting fully cleared out before some new data is being added.

Comment: I would look into the semaphore - something appears to be invalidating it. Let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: A couple of thoughts:

1. Is there a reason you're not using dispatch semaphores? 

2. What is the purpose of the `@autoreleasepool` given that you don't appear to ever drain the pool? I would have thought that you'd want the pool inside the `while` loop, not the other way around. But I don't see any autorelease objects, so that might be academic.

Comment: You never show  what `semaphore_wait ` and `midiReceivedSemaphore` are. There is nothing wrong with dispatch_async and autorelease pools per se.

Comment: 3. It seems that you are a little sloppy in the reading of the buffer and that you could possibly read outside the buffer (e.g. before trying to read `data[packetContentsIndex + 2];`, make sure you've got at least another two bytes).

4. You say it's crashing: Show us the full details of the crash. 5. You are checking to see if the unsigned int length is > 0. Do I infer from this that it returns 0 on failure? You haven't shared that API, so maybe that's fine, but I am suspect when I see a check to see if a unsigned value is positive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob.  I've added a screenshot of the stacktrace, does that help?

Comment: No, I was hoping for an exception code or something like that. This almost just looks like you paused execution while it was waiting for a signal, rather than a crash. Anyway, I've tried manually reproducing the problem by doing stuff like calling `semaphore_destroy` while still waiting, but no luck. Bottom line, we need a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you, and I just can't reproduce the crash you describe on the basis of what's been provided thus far.